# Calling Handlebars helper programmatically in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

One of my components needs to pick a Handlebar helper dynamically based on the provided parameter.

Something like that `{{dynamic-output value=value helper=helper}}`

Inside the component class I would like to output the value based on the provided helper.

I couldn't find much info on using Handlebars helpers programmatically :(

Comment: How many different parameters do you have? You could always nest this logic in more handlebars like `{{#if hasParameterA}} {{dynamic-output value=value helper=helper}} {{/if}}`

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question. My component takes two parameters 'value' and 'helper'. The output of the component is the value with the helper applied.

Comment: What would be an example of 'helper'?

Comment: helper = Handlebars.helper for example I have a helper that converts a date object into a pretty date or formats a number into a dollar value.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you have a helper called `selectBoxOptions` the following code can be used within a helper to call that helper:

`return Handlebars.helpers.selectBoxOptions(selectedValue, options);`

See this blog post for more details: http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/blog/javascript/handlebars-calling-a-helper-function-from-another-helper-231.html

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do.  Here's how:

```
helperFunctionOne(value){
    //Fill with the data manipulation you want for "helperOne"
}

helperFunctionTwo(value){
    //Fill with the data manipulation you want for "helperTwo"
}

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("helperOne", function(value){
    return helperFunctionOne(value);
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("helperTwo", function(value){
    return helperFunctionTwo(value);
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("helperDynamic", function(value, type){
    if(type == 1){
        return helperFunctionOne(value);
    else if(type == 2){
        return helperFunctionTwo(value);
    }
});
```

In the above code, we've set up 2 helper functions and 3 helpers.  You can now call each of these helpers as follows:

```
{{helperOne someValue}}

{{helperTwo someValue}}

{{helperDynamic someValue someType}}
```

Comment: This a great work around. However, I would like to know how to call the actual helper ('helperOne' or 'helperTwo') as oppose to calling the function that the helper is using.

Comment: You're essentially asking for "nesting" of handlebar helpers then, and that's (unfortunately) not supported.

Comment: Nesting helpers is possible. See: http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/blog/javascript/handlebars-calling-a-helper-function-from-another-helper-231.html